# iOS capture UIView with UIImageView inside

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, image-capture

I'm trying to get a UIView screen capture on iOS.

In my view I have two UIImageView with animations.

The code that I using it to capture the view is:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
// Read the UIImage object
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,
                               @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

The result is an image with the background and only one UIImageView. Both ImageViews are in moviming all the time. If I take several pictures, then the  UIImageView is in the same position each time.

Comment: Use self.view.layer.presentationLayer

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
-(CGImageRef)imageCapture
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   CGRect rect= CGRectMake(0,0 ,width, height);

   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);
   return imageRef;
}
```

use the below line whenever you want to capture the screen

```
UIImage *captureImg=[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[self imageCapture]];
```